# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I need to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right)$$ and I always end up with indetermined form. For example since the following holds true $$\frac{1 - x}{1 + x} = \frac{1 + x - 2x}{1 + x} = 1 - \frac{2x}{1 + x} = 1 - \frac{x}{x} \cdot \frac{2}{\frac{1}{x} + 1} = 1 - \frac{2}{\frac{1}{x} + 1},$$ the limit can be rewritten as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\ln\left(1 - \frac{2}{\frac{1}{x} + 1}\right)\right) = \ln\left(-1\right) = \pi i,$$ but I'm in a regular calculus and can't use $i$'s.

Comment: Your limit makes no sense if you restrict only to the reals, as your logarithm is complex except for $|x| < 1$

Comment: Yes, and $\log$ of a negative number isn't well defined : you have to chose which analytic continuation you use

Comment: Ok, I thought it has to be wrong. How did that appear in a regular calculus textbook, however, is a mystery to me.

Comment: (If the equation is $\lim \ln \frac{x-1}{x+1}$, the limit value is 1, and it comes from the continuity of $\log$ function.)

Comment: @tomashauser: regarding your book... maybe there is a misprint in the exercise or the answer could simply be "it does not exist".

Comment: @mrcntn Well, I actually need to find the asymptotes for $f(x)= \ln\left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right)$ which leads to a step in which I have to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\ln\left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)$ but I don't think that the division by $x$ will result in a limit within $\mathbb{R}$ since $\lim_{x \to a}\left(f(x) \cdot g(x)\right) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question, but rather an answer based on additional info given by @thomashauser in a comment. The "full question" asks to find the asymptotes of

$$
h(x) =  \ln\left(\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}\right)  \frac{1}{x} 
$$

First, find the domain: easy to see that the function makes sense only for $|x|<1$. Therefore, you are asked to find the "vertical asymptotes", not the asymptotes at infinity: there is no need to consider the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Clearly you have two  asymptotes at $x=-1$ and $x=1$, both going to negative infinity. You may wonder if there is an additional vertical asymptote at $x=0$. The answer is no: in $x=0$ the function is well defined (the limits $x \rightarrow 0^\pm$ coincide). In fact, you can see that close to the origin

$$ h(x) = -2 -2x^2/3+O(x^3) \, .$$

Final note: $h(x)=h(-x)$, i.e. it is an even function, so you just have to study the limits $x \rightarrow 0^+$ and  $x \rightarrow 1^-$ (or, equivalently, $x \rightarrow 0^-$ and  $x \rightarrow -1^+$).

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the function is $(-1,1)$ and there is no point computing the limit to $\infty$ (nor $-\infty$). For the same reason, there can't be oblique nor horizontal asymptotes.